# Calling a named function in javascript twice

Tags: javascript, ajax, coffeescript

I have a function that loads data into a div, via AJAX, dependent on the value of a select.  The select can be loaded with a predetermined value...or changed.

I need the function to run when the DOM is ready AND if the user changes the select.  Each call to get_data() works if I only include one, or the other...but I if I leave both calls in the code...the second one won't work.

```
  jQuery ->

    f_lesson      = $("#flight_flightlesson_id")
    gi_container  = $("#gradable_items_container")
    load_box      = $("#load_box")
    lesson_tell   = $("#load_box #gradable_items")
    scenario_tell = $("#load_box #scenarios")

    get_data = ->
      if $('#flight_flightlesson_id option[value]:selected').text() == ''
        gi_container.text("You must select a lesson in the 'Flight Info' Tab")
        scenario_tell.text("")
        load_box.removeClass("is-fetching")
        lesson_tell.text "No Lesson Selected"

      else

        $.ajax
          url: "gradable_items_inputs?lesson=#{ f_lesson.val() }"

          beforeSend: ->
            load_box.addClass("is-fetching")
            lesson_tell.text("...loading gradable items")
            scenario_tell.text("...loading scenarios")

          success: (data) ->
            gi_container.html(data).find("#ajax_gradable_items_for_lesson_content")

          complete: ->
            lesson_tell.text("")
            scenario_tell.text("")
            load_box.removeClass("is-fetching")

          error: ->
            lesson_tell.text "ERROR"

  # get_data()

    f_lesson.on "change", ->
      get_data()
```

The first call to get_data() works when the DOM loads...but, then the on change call does not.  If I comment out the first call to get_data, then the on change call works.

Why don't they both work?  Is there an error in my code?  A flaw in my execution?

Comment: It looks you're rewriting DOM in `get_data()` processor. How about using event delegation then?

Comment: My code is actually loading the data via AJAX.  But, the callbacks are only working on the first called get_data().

Comment: How would event delegation help here?  I only have one element (#flight_flightlesson_id) with a change event.

Comment: Is this element overwritten in `$("#gradable_items_container").html(data)`?

Comment: Yes, $("#gradable_items_container").html, will be replaced by updated content.

Comment: Just noticed that if I only use get_data() on select change...it works great once...but after that the callbacks don't work.  The AJAX data is still swapped out...but, no callbacks after the initial change.

Comment: Is `$('#flight_flightlesson_id')` element overwritten in `$("#gradable_items_container").html(data)`? It looks like it is, so you need to use event delegation - make event to be caught on any element that's stable.

Comment: No, #flight_flightlesson_id is just a select menu.  It is not overwritten...it just dictates which nested form fields are loaded. flight_flightlesson_id is not inside of gradable_items_container.

Comment: Please show your HTML structure as well.

Comment: It turns out part of my error was due to using hide on the element that displays the callBack text.  I just removed .hide() and added removeClass().  Now, all seems to be working better.  Still some issue with calling the get_data() twice.  Ill post some html.

Comment: For some reason the Dom call to get_data() is being called over and over and over.

Comment: I updated the code to what Im currently working with

Comment: raina77ow - here is a gist of my code https://gist.github.com/atstockland/7188314

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an indentation issue. `f_lesson.on...` appears to be a level deeper than `get_data`, so by commenting or uncommenting get_data you're moving `f_lesson...` from inside the jQuery() block to the top level.

I think you meant the `get_data()` call to be indented one level deeper.